# Why does a generic parameter need to implement Clone, even if it's inside an Rc?

Tags: generics, rust, clone, encapsulation

These structs:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Inner<T> {
    obj: Rc<RefCell<T>>,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Outer {
    data: Inner<Data>,
}

struct Data {}
```

Give me the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Data: Clone` is not satisfied
--> src\main.rs:23:2
|
23 |     data: Inner<Data>,
|     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected an implementor of trait `Clone`
|
= note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Clone` for `Inner<Data>`
= note: required by `clone`
= note: this error originates in a derive macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I really don't get what's wrong. `Inner` implements `Clone`, which in my head would allow `Outer` to implement `Clone` as well, but the compiler is complaining about `Data`. But `Data` is inside `Rc`, so it wouldn't matter whether it implements `Clone` or not, right?

For example, if I replace the generic `T` directly with `Data`, it compiles:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Inner {
    obj: Rc<RefCell<Data>>,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Outer {
    data: Inner,
}

struct Data {}
```

So why `Data` has to implement `Clone` in the first version?

I'm using Rust 1.49.0.

**Edit:**

This is a known compiler bug:

- https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26925

Comment: With `derive(Clone)` on a generic type, the compiler automatically implements `Clone` where each type parameter is also constrained to `Clone`. You will have to implement `Clone` manually in this case.